# FileSystemWatcher Windows Services in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, email, filesystemwatcher

i have a problem with my new services in WS 2008, my services run in my lab under Windows 7, no problem, but when implement this services in my server, no run, this service providing data for send later for email, this data is a xls file save in my folder "share".

```
    namespace WsEmail
    {

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public partial class WsMail : ServiceBase
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
        Timer tm = new Timer();
        EventLog evLufran = new EventLog();

        public WsMail()
        {
            // Componentes a Iniciar
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void tm_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //DateTime hr = DateTime.Now;
            //if (hr.Hour == 8)
            //{
                OpenWithStartInfo();
            //}
        }

        public void fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Mail(e.FullPath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (EventLog.SourceExists("LufranMail"))
                {
                    EventLog.CreateEventSource("LufranMail", "Application");
                    evLufran.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 234);
                }                
            }               
        }



        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // Creacion del Monitoreo            
            fsw.Path = @"E:\share\";
            fsw.Filter = "*.xls";
            fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.CreationTime;            
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            fsw.Created += fsw_Created;

            // Timer para Ejecutar el OpenWithStarInfo            
            tm.Interval = 1000 * 50;
            tm.Enabled = true;
            tm.Elapsed += tm_Elapsed;

            //evLufran.Source = "LufranMail";
            //evLufran.Log = "Application";
            //evLufran.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = false; 
        }

        void Mail(string eAdjun)
        {
            MailMessage objMail;
            objMail = new MailMessage();
            objMail.From = new MailAddress("", "Notificaciones Lufran", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); //Remitente
            objMail.To.Add(""); //Email a enviar 
            objMail.CC.Add(""); //Email a enviar copia
            objMail.Bcc.Add(""); //Email a enviar oculto
            objMail.Subject = "Clientes con Cotizaciones a 4 semenas (Mercancia por llegar)";
            objMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            objMail.Body = "Verifique por favor la informacion del archivo excel y remitala a los clientes que correspondan";
            objMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            objMail.IsBodyHtml = false; //Formato Html del email
            objMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(eAdjun));
            SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
            SmtpMail.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
            SmtpMail.Port = 587; //asignamos el numero de puerto
            SmtpMail.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //el nombre del servidor de correo
            SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true;
            /*Captura de Errores*/
            try
            {
                SmtpMail.Send(objMail);
                SmtpMail.Dispose();
                objMail.Dispose();
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(eAdjun);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (EventLog.SourceExists("LufranMail"))
                    {
                        EventLog.CreateEventSource("LufranMail", "Application");
                        evLufran.WriteEntry("Archivo no se puede eliminar: " + ex.Message);
                    }

                }                                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!EventLog.SourceExists("LufranMail"))
                {
                    EventLog.CreateEventSource("LufranMail", "Application");
                    evLufran.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
                }                
            }
        }

        public void OpenWithStartInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"E:\Share\xComprasLF.fxp");
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!EventLog.SourceExists("LufranMail"))
                {
                    EventLog.CreateEventSource("LufranMail", "Application");
                    evLufran.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
                }                               
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly happens? Any exceptions or messages?

Comment: Nothing happens, do not send exceptions, no activity, the service is running but not doing its job.

Comment: Did you use a yourTimer.Start() somewhere? I can't find it...

Comment: No, I have not in the code, but in my pc with windows 7 works properly, Could it be that it does not allow it to work? Save a xls file in the path and the FSW is not detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your SMTP code, the first one is that you don't specify a sender, the second one is that you don't specify a recipient and finally you don't provide your credentials to the email server you use. Once you correct this, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer Rafael, but i leave those fields in blank when post the code for security and only information purpose , by the way, i saw a error in my code just in "objMail.To.Add(""); //Email a enviar " the email address has  wrong formatting, the other issue is this service provide data from SQL to Excel, i need that process run not in background and call here "ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"E:\Share\xComprasLF.fxp");" any idea?

Comment: Sorry then, but you should at least put dummy values in those fields, given that there are people who actually expect their code to run with blank properties, specially when they found it like this on the internet.

Comment: The problem with the email address format, it could be that it's using an special character for example a plus (+) sign or something like that, the problem with the database, I can't help you I haven't done FoxPro development, but I encourage you to make a new question with it.

Comment: Thanks for replying rafael, the problem was the time of writing excel file by foxpro process, your time is long and the FSW detects it immediately trying to take possession of the file